# How to get recently added friends with facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm searching for a solution where I can get last 10 added friends for a user.
Is it possible to do via. the FQL or Graph API or something that isn't possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `friends` table/endpoint does not expose the time that you and another user started your friendship. So you can't get this information directly.

The best you can do is query the `stream` table for friend announcements.

```
SELECT description, description_tags, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() 
  AND type = 8 LIMIT 100
```

In my case, this query returned 3 results, even though I requested a `LIMIT` of 100.

Comment: It also returned 3 results in my case. Maybe that's the limit for this query?

Comment: The `stream` table has a lot of restrictions imposed on it, though I've never seen Facebook impose a limit of 3 items. In my case, using a limit of less than 100 returned nothing.